# Организация памяти процесса

Tags: windows, memory, процесс

Прочитал статью на хабре о [организации памяти процесса](https://habrahabr.ru/company/smart_soft/blog/185226/). Только я не понял одного: сегменты памяти(стек, куча, дата сегмент и тд) выделяются для каждого процесса индивидуально? Или существуют одни большие сегменты, которые тянуться на всю память, а для процессов из этих сегментов выделяется по кусочку?

Comment: В современных многозадачных ОС - индивидуально. Причём логически непрерывный блок может состоять из непоследовательных физических блоков.

Answer (score 2):

В Windows, сегмент исключительно логический элемент программы, то есть Windows выделяет только куски памяти, которые процесс видит непрерывно, а на самом деле они могут располагаться как угодно в физической памяти. И сам процесс уже решает где, сколько и под что выделить. ОС это уже не касается, разве что защитных механизмов, но это уже другое. Ни каких глобальных сегментов для всей ОС нет.